# Determine gain, Vo/Vin, of an amplifier for values of x

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

My Equation of the circuit using the node \$V_1\$ is

$$ \frac {V_1-V_o}{(1-x)R_p} + \frac {V_1-0}{xR_p+R_3} - \frac {V_1-0}{R_2}=0 $$

I would like to know how to eliminate or substitute \$V1\$ from the equation (if it's right in the first place!) so that I can combine with the equation \$V_{\text{in}}=-\frac {R_2}{R_1} \cdot V_o\$ (so that I have \$ \frac {V_o}{V_{\text{in}}}\$ and calculate for values of \$x=1\$ and \$x=0.3\$.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation for Vin is wrong. The same current flows through R1 and R2, hence express V1 in terms of Vin.

Also, the last term in the node V1 equation is wrong: \$\Sigma\$currents away from node \$=0\$

Comment: Ok I think the last term in the equation is (V1-Vin)/(R2/(R2+R1)). V1 in terms of Vin is Vin*R2/(R2+R1)=V1. If we replace V1 in the nodal equation with "Vin*R2/(R2+R1)=V1"  can we then transpose for Vo/Vin?

Comment: No, to both. You haven't summed the currents AWAY from node V1 properly. And, use Ohm's law on R1, and then on R2; in other words, do nodal analysis on the node between R1 and R2.

Comment: well there is zero p.d across R1 and R2 so for that we have V1=-IR1 and V1=-IR2

Comment: The node between R1 and R2 is at 0V, therefore there can't be zero across these resistors in general. Use Ohm's law; there's no current flowing into the op amp.

Comment: On the node between R1 and R2 I have 0-Vin/R1 and 0-V1/R2

Comment: Yes, the sum of those two is zero. The V1 nodal equation is also wrong.

Comment: Is the last part of the V1 nodal equation zero?

Comment: No, read my answer again carefully. The last term on the left of the equation wrong.

Comment: The last part should be + 0-Vin/R1 + 0-V1/R2

Comment: Sorry The last part should be + Vin-V1/R1+R2

Comment: We're going in circles here. Your original equation for node V1 is wrong. There are three terms on the left side of the equation, the last term is wrong. The sum of currents AWAY FROM the node must be zero.

Comment: Look at it again. Don't guess.

Comment: The last term should be negated.

Comment: Right, \$(V1-0)/R2\$

Comment: So now we have the V1 equation, we also have the Vin in terms of V1 which is V1/Vin= -R2/R1. Will substituting this inot the V1 nodal equation and simplifying gives an equation for Vo/Vin?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think about this is by considering that the op-amp's real output is at the point called V1. The gain equation with V1 as the output is: -

V1/Vin = -R2/R1 i.e. as per a normal op-amp - if you think about this it'll eventually make sense.

If you want the gain at the real op-amp output Vo, then work out what the attenuation is between Vo and V1 is. If (say) it is 5 then then....

Vo/Vin = -5xR2/R1

Comment: Why does your Vo/Vin equation disregard R3 and the pot?

Comment: It doesn't - I said if the effect of the attenuation is 5:1 i.e. Vo/V1 = 5, then Vo/Vin = -5x R2/R1. The attenuation of "5" is the effect of R3 and the pot.